# Proving $X/Y\cong \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I would like to show that $X=GA_1(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ has a normal subgroup $Y$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, that $X/Y\cong \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ but $X\not\cong \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p^\times $.

$GA(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is the general affine group of matrices $1\times1$ over the field $\mathbb{Z}$ mod $p$ (prime) ([link](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/General_affine_group)). Also $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ is the Multiplicative group of integers modulo $p$ ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)).

I know that in order to prove $X/Y\cong \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ I need to find $Y$ so there is $\phi \ : \ X/Y \to \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. But I can't think of $Y$ and $\phi$ in order to solve this problem. Which group $Y$ and function $\phi$ should solve it and how?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$
It is convenient to think of $X$ as the group of matrices
$$
\Set{\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\
0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}, b \in \mathbb{Z}_p}.
$$

**Hint 1**

> To find $Y$, take the elements with $a = 1$.

**Hint 2**

> To find $\phi$, consider the map that takes the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ to $a$.

Comment: By your hint we get $Y=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1 & b\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}|b\in\mathbb{Z}_{p}\right\}$ but why $Y=\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $X/Y\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times}$?